# Pandas: find duplicates in another dataframe based on a subset

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, subset

Assume DF 1:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  2
2  2  1  1
3  1  9  0
4  9  9  9
```

And DF 2

```
   A  B  C
0  6  1  1
1  1  1  2
2  2  1  1
3  1  9  0
4  1  9  6
```

I would like to add a column to DF 1 with a count of duplicates in DF 2 based on a subset of columns:

For example

Duplicate on

- 1
- 2

Result:

```
   A  B  C  Dupe
0  1  1  1   1
1  1  1  2   1
2  2  1  1   1
3  1  9  0   2
4  9  9  9   0
```

Comment: why 1 1 1 return 1 and  1 9 0 return 2 ?

Comment: because there are 2 rows in DF2 that have A:1 B: 9, and one in DF2 that has A:1 B: 1

Comment: I have two data sources - and want to ensure I can find the rows in DF1 in DF2, but only on some of the columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound like you should `groupby` by df2 then `merge`

```
df=df1.merge(df2.groupby(['A','B']).size().to_frame('DUP').reset_index(),how='left').fillna(0)
   A  B  C  DUP
0  1  1  1  1.0
1  1  1  2  1.0
2  2  1  1  1.0
3  1  9  0  2.0
4  9  9  9  0.0
```

Comment: Works great - what if one of the columns is a float and I want a small tolerance?

Comment: @RML then you need check merge_asof ~

Comment: added a column astype('float').round(0)
then merged on that
then drop

works well enough

many thanks all!